# filtering using having by clause result in unknown column in having clause

Tags: sql, group-by, having

i have a table with these columns: order_date (in yyyy-mm-dd format), order_status, product_sub_category, sales. the data consists of transactions from 2009 onwards. what i want to do is to find the total sales of each product categories in between the year 2011 and 2012. to do that, i use these query:

```
SELECT 
   YEAR(order_date) AS years, 
   product_sub_category,
   SUM(sales) AS sales 
   FROM dqlab_sales_store
WHERE
   order_status = 'order finished' 
   AND product_sub_category = 'Chairs & Chairmats' 
   OR product_sub_category = 'Office Machines' 
   OR product_sub_category = 'Tables' 
   OR product_sub_category = 'Copiers and Fax' 
   OR product_sub_category = 'Telephones and Communication'
GROUP BY
   YEAR(order_date), product_sub_category
HAVING
   YEAR(order_date) > 2011;
```

the problem is that sql tells me unknown column 'order_date' in having clause

any solution? thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use **having** and **where** in the same query.
Try This:

```
    SELECT a.years, a.product_sub_category, sum(sales) as sales
 FROM(
        SELECT 
           YEAR(order_date) AS years, 
           product_sub_category,
           sales
        FROM dqlab_sales_store
        WHERE
           order_status = 'order finished' 
           AND (product_sub_category = 'Chairs & Chairmats' 
           OR product_sub_category = 'Office Machines' 
           OR product_sub_category = 'Tables' 
           OR product_sub_category = 'Copiers and Fax' 
           OR product_sub_category = 'Telephones and Communication')) as a
    GROUP BY
       a.years, 
       a.product_sub_category
    HAVING
       a.years > 2011;
```

Comment: apparently this still doesn't solve the problem as now i have 'unknown column a.order_date  in group statement' :(

Comment: check the edit @dityamahandaru

Comment: Then pls give the click mark to accept the answer.